# Forgot Password - what fields should I add?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on the Forgot Password functionality.

User type their email address on the forgot password page and then hash token link will be sent via email.

the token will look something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/account/resetpassword/4u240238402348239048092384908239080
```

If user click on that link then it will search for hash token from user `users` table. If found, then show text fields to change password.

I will be using `hash("sha256",...)` function to generate hash.

How should the hash should be stored in the `users` table?

Do I need to add fields like "reset_hash" and "reset_date" ?

Comment: I would also take care that users couldn't spoof the hash using injection or some other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should add two columns:  one for the reset hash and another for the timestamp when the reset was issued.  The latter should be used to make sure the password is reset within a certain time frame.

The hash and/or time should also be removed once a password reset has taken place, to prevent future resets using the same hash.

Comment: What the value of reset hash and and timestamp should be when the password has been changed? to null/blank i guess?

Comment: @user791022:  Yes, either will work.  Just make sure a user can't go to `http://www.domain.com/account/resetpassword/` and issue a password reset on users whose hashes and blank/NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's a good idea to store that fields in the users table. The you can check for the hash to be valid and block it setting the reset_date to the actual datetime. May be it's a good idea to store an expire_date field too.

Answer (score 1):

Store the hash as varchar(256) and you would probably want a request date, I would just use an int field storing time() when the request is received so that you can simply do a time() - {dbtime} and if it is over a certain value then the request has timed out.

EDIT: As above, you should set both of these fields to NULL when the request has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the right thing, but i would suggest to create a separate table for one-time-actions like this. To me it seems the user table is just not the right place to store this information.

If you create a separate table, you could later add other types of actions, like email confirmation etc, and add fields like an expiry date. If the action was executed, you can simply delete the entry from the table.